# Android how to get 10 closes geopoint from current position

Tags: android

Let say I have my current position.

I also have 400 other geopoint.

I'd like to find out what are the 10 closest geopoint.

What I'd like to avoid is to go through all the 400 points and compare the distance between 2 geopoint.

Is there a way do get this information more efficiently? Maybe something exposed throught the mapview? or mapviewcontroller?

Comment: I was trying to do something similar but I did not find more efficient way. If something shows up, please do share it here.

Comment: excuse me, but how you determine if the 10 geopoints you choose are the closEST if you do not verify all of them?

Comment: I was wondering MAYBE something with the latitude and longitude values that you could maybe eliminate some that are really far away

Comment: Basically i would like to avoid going through the 400 ... so narrow down some and do distance calculation, but it would of been great if the map exposed something already since it knows about the overlay that was added on the map ....

Comment: this is impossible, unless you know some other information, such as a trajectory or something. If you are getting these 400 points by querying, then likely you can say what the radius distance is and then limit the amount of points recieved.

Comment: maybe some preproccesing, to sort them by the longitude or latitude and then first calculate only the long/lat distance because if it is to far than it is not what are you looking for. And after that search in the other dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing distances, compare "the square of the distance".

If you are at x0, y0, get the points whose (xn - x0)² + (yn - y0)² are the lowest.
This way you can obtain the nearest points avoiding squared toots (computationally expensive), and you will have to do just sums (differences) and products, which are cheap in computation terms.

If you need the distances, get the square roots only of the 10 selected nearest points.

Comment: interesting where did you get the formula?

Comment: I see what you did there, its the pythagorean. Makes sense

Comment: you still have to test all 400 results tho.

Answer (score 1):

excuse me, but how you determine if the 10 geopoints you choose are the closEST if you do not verify all of them?

You might detect 10 "reasonably close" points without checking them all, just fill a buffer with the first 10 points close to you in the list you fetched from the data source which are within a certain range (lets say 10 miles?)

this way you get some very close points and the speed will get a boost. Of course, when you gain from a side, you must leave from another. So it is speed vs accuracy imho.

Comment: But withing 10 miles you still have to go through the 400 points and check if its under 10 miles don't you?

Comment: no you dont, you might be lucky and stop after 10. If you are going to be forced to check all 400 it means that you haven't find at least 10 points within 10miles!

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Morton Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) to sort your Points. The Morton Order maps i.e. 2d coordinates into 1d and preserves the locality of the points.

That means, if the closest neighbor (in 2d) of point **x** is **y** then those points are directly next to each other in Morton Order. 
To find the 10 closest points around x you would have to look much less points.

Comment: but you still have to sort the points - hence you have to analyze them all.

Comment: No you don't have to analyse them all, sorting can be done in O(log n) and the nearest neighbor search is also a O(log n) algorithm